# Split delimited column into single column

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, pandas-melt

I have a vendor supplied file that stores `n` medications in a single column separated by `;`. I'm struggling trying to `melt`, then `groupby` the *dateframe*.

```
meds = meds.melt(id_vars=['Vendor', 'patientid'], value_name='Medication')
meds = meds.loc[meds['Medication'].notnull()]
```

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

but since *'variable'* changes, the aggregation is going to be wrong.

```
meds_final = meds.groupby(['Vendor', 'patientid', 'Medication']).count()
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your data as code or link so we can reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

turns out after I split the column I forgot to strip it, so 'Drug A' was ' Drug A' or '  Drug A', hence the groupby wasn't doing what I was hoping :-)